# Error with tikzcd and baposter

Tags: errors, tikz-cd, baposter

```
\documentclass[landscape,final,a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{}{}{}{}{}

\headerbox{Lorem ipsum}{name=lipsum,column=0,row=0}{

\[\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d,"id"] \\
C \arrow[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}\]

}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options
```

I've tried using ampersand replacement and it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to issue an `ampersand replacement` here.

```
\documentclass[landscape,final,a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{}{}{}{}{}

\headerbox{Lorem ipsum}{name=lipsum,column=0,row=0}{

\[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \& B \arrow[d,"id"] \\
C \arrow[r] \& B
\end{tikzcd}\]

}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason is that the `tikzcd` environment is in the argument to another command (here `\headerbox`) and this situation *requires* `ampersand replacement`.