# Can't include theorem in my poster

Tags: amsthm, posters, tikzposter

Context: I'm doing a poster using `tikzposter`. Also I'm on ShareLatex, I suspect it might be source of the problem as well.

Problem: I can't add a theorem, this is simply ignored when I compile. Here is a sample:

First:

```
  \documentclass[18pt, a0paper, portrait, noamsthm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathfrak{h}}
\renewcommand{\b}{\mathfrak{b}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\tilde{\mathcal{N}}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} 
\title{Talk}
\author{Nicolas Hemelsoet}
\date{\today}


\usetheme{Simple}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{test}{
\begin{theorem}
Hi
\end{theorem}
}

\end{document}
```

For the first code, I got this answer:

> There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the `\item` command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

Any help is really appreciated, many thanks in advance !

Comment: @egreg that does not explain the first one (I find the structure in tikzposter confusing, so gave up debuging)

Comment: @egreg : thank you ! Now the diagrams are working but I still can't obtain a theorem. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @daleif : do you advice me to switch on baposter ?

Comment: I don't use either, I did a poster some months back, just trying to where I put the code, that was very easy to use and a much easier interface. I don like the combination of `\block` and `theorem`, there are probably some lists involved that does not like each other

Comment: Now that's just about theorems, I retracted the close vote.

Comment: Found it, I actually used the `memoir` class (does not matter) but the poster was build around the `poster` part of the  `tcolorbox` package, it has some quite nice features. See for example: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-tutorial-poster.pdf

Comment: Apparently, `amsthm` is not compatible with `tikzposter`.

Comment: @egreg : thank you ! If you post this as an anwser I would accept it. Do you know if it's compatible with baposter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with tikzcd and baposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435339/error-with-tikzcd-and-baposter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remove the loading of `amsthm` there is no error.

If you need to style your theorems, you can use `ntheorem`.

Comment: can you be more precise by what you mean removing amsthm? Are you defining theorem environments? Can you provide an example. This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @N8tron The `amsthm` package is not needed for using `\newtheorem`. It provides additional bells and whistles for defining theorems. But it's incompatible with `tikzposter`.

Answer (score 2):

Saving a piece of advice for the future generations: I had a similar issue when writing a document with lots of custom theorem environments (all created with `amsthm`). When I first used one of them, this issue appeared. The code that defined it was

```
\newtheorem{escoliox}[teoremax]{Escólio}   
\newenvironment{escolio}
    {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}\escoliox}
    {\popQED\escoliox}
```

After inspecting the code for some time and testing with other custom environments, I discovered the problem was that i hadn't closed the `escoliox` environment when defing `escolio`. Therefore, when changing the first code to

```
\newtheorem{escoliox}[teoremax]{Escólio}   
\newenvironment{escolio}
    {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}\escoliox}
    {\popQED\endescoliox}
```

the problem dissapeared. Oh, I was using Overleaf v2 (which is Overleaf + ShareLaTeX), but I believe this things might not be relevant for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since I really want to keep using `amsmath` and `tikzposter`, I found a (very ugly) workaround:

Add a line with `\item` (and an optional negative vertical space so that the added `item` does not ruin the aesthetics of the poster) before the environment. For example:

```latex
\vspace{-1cm} \item
\begin{theorem}
    All humans are mortal.
\end{theorem}
```