# Strange missing \item with tikzposter and amsthm

Tags: amsthm, tikzposter

Seems that there is a weird interaction with amsthm and tikzposter

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{defi}{Definition}


\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{1}
\block{Methodology}{ 
    \begin{defi}
       Hello World
    \end{defi}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Results in a missing \item error and we lose the **Definition.**

[image: Missing Definition label and \item error]

Puttting an \item in the \block eliminates the error.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{defi}{Definition}


\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{1}
\block{Methodology}{\item 
    \begin{defi}
       Hello World
    \end{defi}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Gives some screwy spacing but no more errors and **Definition.** label is there:

[image: \item added to "fix" error]

I've tried it with multiple definitions and only the first one is broken.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{1}
\block{Methodology}{ 
    \begin{defi}
       Hello World
    \end{defi}
    \begin{defi}
       Hello World (again)
    \end{defi}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Yeilds:
[image]

Comment: Yes, there are some issues between `amsthm` and `tikzposter`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435970/82917. I fear the state of the art is "use `ntheorem`".